# API call from VBA

Tags: vba, api, post

I don't know much about API, in fact, almost nothing. I used Google POSTMAN to make a POST request to extract some data from Adaptive Insights. What I would like to do is execute the call from Excel VBA and update an Excel sheet when I need by pressing a button.

Here is the snippet from POSTMAN:

```
     POST /api/v13 HTTP/1.1
     Host: api.adaptiveinsights.com
     Authorization: Basic ZmlubWdyX3NhbGVzQHN0ZW1jZWxsLmNvbTpBZGFwdGl2ZTE=
     Content-Type: application/xml
     cache -Control: no -cache
     Postman-Token: 650bd3ad-82e9-aa33-ae77-ee4d89ff0fd8

     <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
     <call method="exportData" callerName="Export.xlsx">
     <credentials login="******@****.com" password="*****"/>
     <version name="FY2017-November V2" isDefault="false"/>
     <format useInternalCodes="true" includeUnmappedItems="false"/>
     <filters>
     <timeSpan start="Jan-2017" end="Feb-2017"/></filters>
      <rules includeZeroRows="false" includeRollups="true" markInvalidValues="false" markBlanks="false"
     timeRollups="single">
     </rules>
     </call>
```

Here is the output from POSTMAN

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <response success="true">
     <output><![CDATA[Account Name,Account Code,Level Name,Rollup
      .......................................................
```

I did a fair bit of googling and this is what I have so far for my macro:

```
      myURL = "https://api.adaptiveinsights.com/api/v13"
      xmlHTTP.Open "POST", myURL, False
      xmlHTTP.SetCredentials "****@****.com", "*****",    HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER
      xmlHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml"
      xmlHTTP.Send

      Set xmlResult = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

      xmlResult.LoadXML xmlHTTP.ResponseText
```

My questions are:

1. How do I connect to this specific set of data - "FY2017-November V2" that has  timeSpan start ="Jan-2017" end="Feb-2017".
2. How do I load the data into Excel, in essence, do in VBA what I did in POSTMAN?

The data looks like this:

There are four fields - 3 text and one numeric (Account Name,Account Code,Level Name,Rollup):

"6020 Staff Benefit", 6020, "Accounting-Corp", 20.3252

Would really appreciate any help.

Thank you

Valglad

Comment: So, is return format Xml ?  Either you can drill in to the Xml with VBA code using the MSXML2 library (which you already have referenced).  Or you can experiment with the Excel User Interface and use macro recorder to see sample code.   I know for a fact that Excel can do many things if you try to open an xml file (it's just I never go down that path).

Comment: It's not clear from your question what the exact problem is: getting the results from the API call, or parsing the returned data? If the latter then it would help to show more of the API output than the small snippet you included.  Looks like a table of data expressed as "csv" format (in a CDATA section), so you will not be able to use standard XML methods to parse out the individual data points.  Show more of that if that's where you need help.

Comment: Please *edit your question* to add the sample data

Answer (score 0):

I think your auth is wrong here.  Put all of the XML into a single variable, including the authentication credentials.  For Adaptive Insights this is just part of the XML text.

```
request = "<?xml version=  ... </call>"
URL = "https://api.adaptiveinsights.com/api/v13"
Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objXML.Open "POST", URL, False
objXML.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
objXML.send (request)
xmlResponse = objXML.responsetext
MsgBox (xmlResponse)
```

Should see the first part of the response in the message box.  You've still got a job of work to parse out the CDATA block but that's just text manipulation.