# VBA: Using Filesystemobject to locate workbook path

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the GetFolder method within FileSystemObject to locate the path of a workbook. I am then using the path to search for filenames in the same directory and extract information from files with certain names using some parameters. It works fine when working from the windows directory, however the company I work at uses Sharepoint. When accessing the Excel-workbook from Sharepoint this method no longer works. The workbook opens fine, but when I run the Macro I get an error message.

Code in question:

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(Application.Thisworkbook.Path)
```

Error: Unable to find path (Swedish literal error message: Det går inte att hitta filsökvägen)

Anyone with a clue as to what to do about this? I've tried some alternate ways to get the path but nothing has worked thus far.

Comment: Sharepoint uses https paths, not the regular file system, so there's no way to use FSO to search that path.

Comment: Try: Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("​
https://sharepoint.sharepoint.com/si...rt%20v2.6.xlsm
") or Set OutputFile = Workbooks.Open("​
https://sharepoint.sharepoint.com/si...rt%20v2.6.xlsm
")

with full link to file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it would be cleaner use WinHttp object to get the SP library's contents via SharePoint REST API. It's how Microsoft wants you to approach this problem anyway. Refer to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41232161/api-call-from-vba) and [SP REST API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service?tabs=csom).

There is also a dirty way to this we found a few years ago. If you sync a library's contents to your File Explorer, there's a good chance FSO could work. But keep in mind that the synced library is better kept up-to-date. Also, SharePoint can handle much longer paths than FSO, so when hierarchies get deep, you'll only get the first 250-something characters.

Therefore, I'd use the API.